# RMI Method not supported by remote object: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: unrecognized method hash

Tags: java, server, rmi

I'm having a weird problem in my Bank - Client (server client via RMI) application.

I have Bank class that implements IBank extends Remote.  This Bank Class has several methods, checkClient, getBankAccount etc.

The problem is, I can call the method checkClient (boolean) just fine from the clientside, all other methods give the UnmarshalException

Bank class on serverside:

```
public class Bank extends UnicastRemoteObject implements IBank { 

    private BankName bankName;

    private String URL;

    @Override
    public boolean checkClient(String username, String password) {
        Client client = db.getClient(username, password);

        if(client.getUsername() == null && client.getPassword() == null){
        System.out.println("Client not found in " + getBankName() + "database");
            return false;
        }

        System.out.println(client.toString() + " connected to bank succesfully");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<BankAccount> getAccounts(Client c) throws RemoteException {
       System.out.println("WORKED");
       return null;
    }
}
```

Interface implemented by Bank Class:

```
public interface IBank extends Remote{

    String getURL() throws RemoteException;

    String getBankName() throws RemoteException;

    boolean checkClient(String Username, String Password) throws RemoteException;

    ArrayList<BankAccount> getAccounts(Client c) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Serializable object used by Bankmethod:

```
public class BankAccount implements Serializable {

}
```

*above examples are just pieces of the complete application

I can't figure out why the 'checkClient' method works just fine, and the getAccounts (and other methods not included in code above) give the UnmarshalException.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

**EXAMPLE**

Below you can find the method I use to connect a Client to a Bank:

```
@Override
public

ArrayList<BankAccount> connectToBank(Client c) throws RemoteException {
    assert(c != null);

    ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts;        

    if(!Bank.checkClient(c.Username, c.Password)){
        System.out.println("bank.checkclient == false, Client not found");
        return null;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Client found in " + Bank.getBankName() + " database");
    }

    System.out.println("Calling bank.getaccounts");
    accounts = Bank.getAccounts(c);

    if(accounts == null){
        System.out.println("No accounts found for " + c.Username);
    }

    return accounts;        
}
```

When I use a username and password that doesn't exist, console prints out:

```
Server IP Address: localhost
Server Port number 9000
Client: Registry located
Client: Bank and Publisher are bound
bank.checkclient == false, Client not found
```

and returns null;

However when I use a username and password that **does** exist, console prints out:

```
Server IP Address: localhost
Server Port number 9000
Client: Registry located
Client: Bank and Publisher are bound
Client found in RABO database
Calling bank.getaccounts
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.keyReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:136)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.callAction(ButtonBehavior.java:106)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$74(BehaviorBase.java:135)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:147)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:227)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: unrecognized method hash: method not supported by remote object
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:354)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.getAccounts(Unknown Source)
    at Client.Client.connectToBank(Client.java:240)
    at Client.FXMLClientController.btnLogIn_clicked(FXMLClientController.java:232)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: unrecognized method hash: method not supported by remote object
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:294)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

So you can see the Bank.checkClient works fine, the Bank.getAccounts causes the problem

Comment: Interface BankAccount?

Comment: Hint: consider adding some of your exception stack traces. Nobody here got a crystal ball to understand what your application is doing on your systems unless you tellus.

Comment: Yes Joop, already tried adding a 'IBankAccount extends Remote' interface and having the BankAccount implement it, however this didn't solve the problem. Same exact UnmarshalException popped up

Comment: Hm, are really **all** calls failing; or did you just try the `getAccounts()` one? You see, for `getAccounts()` your code has to marshal/transfar/unmarshal objects of two "non-standard" classes - Client and BankAccount. Of course, if one of those two wouldn't serialize ... then you run into problems. Or if there is a version conflict for the concrete classes involved. That is why we **really really** need to see those exception messages.

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. If a class wasn't serializable you would see a different exception.

Answer (score 1):

You've changed something about the remote interface without recompiling and redeploying everything. Do a clean build, redeploy, retest.

Answer (score -1):

I still haven't figured out the exact problem, however the problem occured exclusively when I was trying to send a custom object via RMI. Methods that return String, boolean, int etc. from the Bank worked fine. When I tried sendig a BankAccount (customobject) the problem occured.

I fixed it with merging the Client-project and the Bank-project together, now they use the exact same Interfaces and Classes so the Unmarshal-problem went away

hope this helps someone

Comment: The exact problem was stated in my answer two days earlier, and you fixed it by recompiling and redeploying, as also stated in my answer.